# Angular Routing is not working after logging in

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to login using username and password and displaying a home page.

Homepage contains hyperlink, clicking that should direct to someother content which is not happening.

Can someone help me in this regard.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/login', {
       templateUrl: 'pages/login.html',
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
      }).
      when('/home',{
          templateUrl: 'pages/country-list.html',
          controller:'CountryListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/:countryName',{
          templateUrl: 'pages/country-detail.html',
          controller:'CountryDetailCtrl'
      }).
     otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
      });
  });


app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'Auth', function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event) {
        console.log('Auth logged:'+Auth.isLoggedIn());
        if (!Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
            console.log('DENY');
            event.preventDefault();
            $location.path('/login');
        }
        else {
            console.log('ALLOW');
            $location.path('/home');
        }
    });
}]);

app.factory('Auth', function(){
    var user;
    console.log('user'+user);
    return{
        setUser : function(aUser){
            user = aUser;
        },
        isLoggedIn : function(){
            return(user)? user : false;
        }
      }
    });

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$rootScope','$scope','$location', 'Auth',function($rootScope,$scope,$location, Auth) {

    $scope.$watch(Auth.isLoggedIn, function (value, oldValue) {
        console.log('value'+value);
        console.log('not value'+!value);
        console.log('oldValue'+oldValue);
        if(!value && oldValue) {
          console.log("Disconnect");
          $location.path('/login');
        }

        if(value) {
          console.log("Connect");
          //Do something when the user is connected
        }

      }, true);

    $rootScope.user = {};

  $scope.login = function (username, password) {

    if ( username === 'admin' && password === '1234') {

        $rootScope.user.name= username;
        $rootScope.user.password= password;
        Auth.setUser($scope.user);
        $location.path( '/home' );

    } else {
        $scope.loginError = "Invalid username/password combination";
    };
  };


}]);

app.controller('CountryListCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('json/countries.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.countries = data;
    });
  });

app.controller('CountryDetailCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams,$location){
    console.log('countrName route'+$routeParams.countryName);
    $scope.name = $routeParams.countryName;
    console.log('countrName $scope.name'+$scope.name);

  });
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div ng-view></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

### Login.html

```
<h1>Login Page</h1>

<form ng-submit="login(username, password)" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid">
  <label>User name</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="username" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="password" ng-model="password" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
  <br/>
  {{loginError}}  {{loggedUser}}
  <br/><br/>
  <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="">Submit</button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

### country-list.html

```
<h1>Country List</h1>
<div>Welcome :<strong>{{user.name}}</strong></div>
<span class="logout"><a href="" ng-click="logoutUser()">Logout</a></span>
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="country in countries"><a href="#/{{country.name}}">{{country.name}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

### country-detail.html

```
<h1>Country Detail</h1>
<h1>{{name}}</h1>
```

Problem is with CountryDetailCtrl I guess. but cosnole values are coming fine.

Can someone let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: can you provide your html?

Comment: Provided html files I have in my app.

Comment: it's working in this [example](https://curran.github.io/screencasts/introToAngular/exampleViewer/#/37)

Answer (score 0):

no need in $rootScope here just use one call of

```
 if (!Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
     console.log('DENY');
     $location.path('/login');
     return; // not to execute your controller function further
 }
```

on start of each of you view controllers, that should be protected, "return" will stop execution of controller code written bellow.